# creating IList<T> values at runtime from variables

Tags: c#

Im getting data from a solaceconnection which returns data as so {Account:"023": hasAccount:true} and I need to break it up and put it into two list (IList names and IList values). Names will be "Account" and "hasAccount" which I am able to do. But, Im having a problem with values. I am trying to get  the type of the values ("023" and true in this example) and creating IList of type string" for "023" and IList of type bool for true. I have been trying the below but

```
Cache.ToList().ForEach(row => {
List<string> _namesList = new List<string>();
List<object> _valuesList = new List<object>();

FieldInfo[] fields = row.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);
                
fields.ToList().ForEach(field => {
                    
                    var fieldName = field.Name;
                    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(row);
                    _namesList.Add(fieldName);
        
                    var m_oEnum = Activator.CreateInstance(fieldValue.GetType(), new object[] { 1 }); // Length 1
                    
                    //var m_oEnum = new propertyType[] { fieldValue };
                    _valuesList.Add(m_oEnum);
                });
});
```

My intentions with var m_oEnum is to create a IList or array of type stirng or bool and set the fieldvalue in it. But Im not able to do it since i get the exception thrown "Constructor on type 'System.Boolean' not found." for line

```
  var m_oEnum = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, new object[] { 1 }); // Length 1
```

is it possible to create an array on the fly with a datatype and place the value in it? Thanks

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What does this all accomplish, and why?

Comment: Also, `Type.GetType(fieldValue.GetType().ToString())` can be reduced to `fieldValue.GetType()`.

Comment: have to pass it in a function with this signature InitliseCol(IList<string> names, IList<object> values)

Comment: @madreflection i had that originally i was still getting the same error

Comment: Well, go back to it. That's not the problem. `Type.GetType` can be unreliable and cause more problems than you already have.

Comment: You say you're trying to create a list, but your code is actually trying to create an object of the same type as the value you already have. You've already got a list (`_valuesList`) that's perfectly capable of holding booleans and strings. Why not just do `_valuesList.Add(fieldValue)`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior im tryinng to do this bec the function that I pass the values list to check each value as so if(values[colIndex] is IEnumerable<string> ) if I just add it in valueList it doesnt meet that condition

Comment: Then you'll need to create a generic type of List to pass into your activator (`typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(fieldValue.GetType())`) and then add your value to that list by reflection. I do think if you took a step back you might find that the overall problem you're trying to solve shouldn't require this. It's weird that the consuming code is looking for a generic collection, when you've only got a scalar value in your fields.

Answer (score -1):

Value types should be handled differently.

```
Cache.ToList().ForEach(row => {
List<string> _namesList = new List<string>();
List<object> _valuesList = new List<object>();

FieldInfo[] fields = row.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance);
                
fields.ToList().ForEach(field => {
                
                var fieldName = field.Name;
                var fieldValue = field.GetValue(row);
                _namesList.Add(fieldName);
                var objectType = fieldValue.GetType();
                if (objectType.IsValueType) 
                {
                    _valuesList.Add(fieldValue);
                }
                else
                { // What about types without a parameterless constructor?
                    var m_oEnum = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, new object[] { 1 }); // Length 1
                
                    _valuesList.Add(m_oEnum);
                 }
            });
});
```

Comment: where does objectType come from? Fieldvalue.gettype will error out

Comment: I thought it was the activator giving the error, not the GetType()